# Converting a view from JavaFX to HTML

Tags: java, html, javafx

I wrote a Java **desktop application** using **JavaFX** with `xml` files. Is it possible to "port" it leaving all the code unchanged, just using **`html`** files instead (for the **web application** version)? I would like to keep `@FXML` tags as they are, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

HTML and FXML (which I assume was what you meant by 'xml' because you need fxml to run a JavaFX application) are similar only on a surface level.

HTML - HyperText Markup Language
FXML - FX Markup Language

They both use 'tags' to 'markup' content, letting whatever program that reads it know how to display the given information, but they are not the same.

A browser displaying a webpage expects certain HTML tags to be there, like `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>` and does not understand other tags, such as FXML's `<Pane>` tag, or `<ComboBox>` tag. The browser would not know how to display this AT ALL, just as a JavaFX application would not know how to display a `<br>` tag.

---

Now, view aside, could you use the same back-end code for both applications? **Yes.** You would need to put all the necessary code somewhere they both could access it, so, in your JavaFX application your method might look like this:

```
@FXML
public void doSomething(ActionEvent e){
    MyJavaServer.doSomething();
}
```

and in your web based application, you could use Spring Framework or something to produce code that calls the same `MyJavaServer.doSomething()`.

Comment: Plus, the controller for a web application sits in the server's memory, and is reused for multiple (transient) requests for a view from multiple clients. The controller for a JavaFX application is in the client memory, and persists potentially for the lifespan of the entire application. It holds (persistent) references to the UI controls and deals with just a single client. The lifespan of these things is completely and utterly different.

Comment: @James_D makes a good point, you don't actually *want* a desktop application and a web application to use the same code or function the same way, they have vastly different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be possible with some kind of transpiler like [cheerpj](https://www.leaningtech.com/cheerpj/) or [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) or [tee-vm](http://teavm.org/)

But JavaFx depends on an embedded webview. This will make it harder, if not impossible to reuse the Fx frontends.